# get statistics information by SQL query efficiently for table with 3 columns and 800 million rows

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, windows-7

I have a data table with 3 columns and 800 million rows in SQL server database.

```
  locationID     cardID    value
  NY_xxxxx     xxxxxx    xxxx.xxxx   // x : integer digits from 0 to 9
  NY_xxxxx     xxxxxx    xxxx.xxxx  
  NY_xxxxx     xxxxxx    xxxx.xxxx  
  IA_xxxxx     xxxxxx    xxxx.xxxx  
  IA_xxxxx     xxxxxx    xxxx.xxxx  
  IA_xxxxx     xxxxxx    xxxx.xxxx  
  ...
```

I need to count the distinct numbers of cardID for the same location.

Also, I need to count location numbers in the same state. For example, for NY in the above table, we have 3 locations.

I also need to know how many locations in each state, and how many cardID in each location and how many cardID in each state.

How to get these statistics information by SQL query efficiently? The data table size is large.

Comment: Your database design does not lend itself to efficiency.  Specifically, your locationID field is bad.

Comment: @Dan Bracuk, could you please explain more clearly ? why no efficiency ? how to get the needed information  ? thanks !

Comment: For the people who vote my post down, please given a reason. this my help me improve my post quality. Thanks !

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT cardID),locationid FROM table GROUP BY locationid` An index on location would help.Add a WHERE clause if you want a specific location.

Comment: is there more than one cardID per locationID?

Comment: An index on locationID would help as said, but on a table with 800,000,000 rows, make sure you've sufficient server resources for such an index, if your database is already reaching server capacity.

Comment: @Brett Schneider, yes, it is possible.

Comment: The locationID is inefficient because you have to use functions to get specific states.  A relational model would be better.  If you actually have one, you should have mentioned it.

Comment: @Dan Bracuk, i only have the table, what kinds of model you need to get the information ?

Comment: MySQL is not SQL server

Comment: @Mihai, the table may have tens of thousands of locations, I need to know how many cardID for each location. Example, for NY_1234, I have 150 cardID, and also, for NY state, I have 3600 cardID and so on. THanks !

Comment: @Brett Schneider, I get the information of row number.

Comment: The "relational model" that was mentioned is because you should have the location ID as a foreign key to a location table, which will hold an ID field, and a location field.

Comment: @i-CONICA, I do not have the model. Thanks !

Comment: With a database that size you should pay someone to restructure it for you before it becomes too unmanageable.

Comment: @i-CONICA preferably by inventing a time machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP probably already knows this, but here is how to get the answer, disregarding efficiency.  First, cards per location, as described in the comments:

```
SELECT locationid, COUNT(DISTINCT cardID)
FROM table 
GROUP BY locationid
```

Next the same thing per state.

```
SELECT substring(locationid, 1, 2) state, COUNT(DISTINCT cardID)
FROM table 
GROUP BY substring(locationid, 1, 2)
```

For a single state,

```
select COUNT(DISTINCT cardID)
from table 
where substring(locationid, 1, 2) = 'NY'
```

The problem with the first query is that it will return locationID's like NY_1234.  If you have not memorized what NY_1234 is in layman's terms, Rochester for example, you have to go outside your database to see what it is.

The second query will be inefficient because it has to apply the substring function on a large number of records.  The third will be inefficient because it will have to scan the entire table.

If you had a relational model you could do stuff like this.

```
select municipality, count(distinct cardID)
from table join location on table.locationid = location.locationID
group by municipality

select stateCode, count(distinct cardID)
from table join location on table.locationid = location.locationID
group by stateCode
```

State codes would be NY, NJ, etc  If you wanted New York, New Jersey, etc, that would simply be another field.

Finally,

```
select count(distinct cardID)
from table join location on table.locationid = location.locationID
where stateCode = 'NY'
```

The second two relational queries would be faster than the single table queries because they wouldn't have to use functions.  You could speed it up even more with an index on stateCode, but even if you didn't, a much smaller table would be scanned.

Comment: how to improve efficiency for the first two queries ?