# efficient analysis for large data set by SQL or R?

Tags: sql, sql-server, r, bigdata

I have a data file with 800 million rows and 3 columns. The csv file size is 30 GB.

I need to do some analysis on the data. It took very long time to load it to SQL server.
Also, it took about 10 minutes to a SQL query like:

```
 SELECT MAX(VALUE) AS max_s
 FROM [myDB].[dbo].[myTable]
```

Also, I need to do other statistics analysis for each column.

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) as num_rows, COUNT(DISTINCT VARIABLE1) as num_var1 FROM [myDB].[dbo].[myTable]
```

If I want to improve the analysis/query efficiency , SQL server or other tools can help me ?

How about R ? But, my laptop has only 8 GB memory. It is impossible to load the whole data in to a data frame.

More info about data is here
[get statistics information by SQL query efficiently for table with 3 columns and 800 million rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23390699/get-statistics-information-by-sql-query-efficiently-for-table-with-3-columns-and)

Some solutions have been given. I really appreciate. But, I would like to find out whether we have more efficient solutions.

Comment: If you want to play with big data you will need big boxes (or big patience), no other way around it.

Comment: Have you created indexes on the columns in your table ? That will make things faster.

Comment: Are the data file and csv file the same thing?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the format of the table you are using for the SQL query.  You have answered your own question about R:  the data doesn't fit into memory with the basic product.

Comment: @Dan Bracuk, I appreciate your answers to my previous question. I just want to find more efficient ones. Thanks!

Comment: @Gordon Linoff, if R is limited by computer memory size, how to do analysis for large data set by R ? Thanks !

Comment: @user3440244 . . . Lots of data can fit into the memories of modern computers.  And there are extensions of R and products based on R that support even larger data sets.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff, what are the extensions of R ? Could you please give an example ? thanks !

Comment: @user3440244 . . . An excellent source for analytics software (and other things related to analytics) is www.kdnuggets.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can greatly speed up your SQL queries by indexing your data, especially with large tables.

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX index_name
ON [myDB].[dbo].[myTable] (value, cardID, locationID)
```

The command above creates a clustered index for your table. Place your actual column names within the round brackets. A clustered index sorts your rows in the order specified within the round brackets. You can create additional non-clustered indexes, but it is generally advisable to have at least one clustered index on your table.

If you have a unique identifier (e.g. an id for each observation that is truly distinct) in your data, you can create a **UNIQUE INDEX** by using the CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement. This is generally the best way to speed up your queries.

Generally speaking, again, you should index your data in descending order of cardinality; this means that the columnn with most distinct values goes first in your "ON table (...)" statement, followed by columns with gradually fewer distinct values.

[Index syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_index.asp)

[Some more information on indexes](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/190263/Indexes-in-MS-SQL-Server)